# Capture the result from the terminal (external process)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, terminal

I need to get the result from the terminal

```
mask = "audio"
a = os.system("ls -l | grep %s | awk '{ print $9 }'" % mask)
print a # a = 0, that's the exit code

#=>
file1_audio
file2_audio
0
```

This command just **prints** the result to the console, while I want to capture it to a variable.

Comment: What you are trying to do here could also just be done in pure Python.

Comment: @Keith, that's just an example, I have a more serious task.

Comment: Then you could use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) module to run a pipeline and read the stdout.

Comment: @Keith, if I could, I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: the link to the documentation in my previous comment shows how to do it. But we don't know what the "more serious" task is. If it's an app that puts the terminal in raw mode then that won't work. If it's that trivial, I'm sure Python could just do it.

Comment: @Keith, I tried it and failed.

Comment: Please add to your question what you tried, and how it failed.

Comment: @Keith, I don't want for some reason.

Comment: Please read the FAQ. You are expected to have that in you question, if possible. Also, this is a common question and there are many answers to this already.

Comment: Note that if you'd just glanced at [the docs for `os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) they would have recommended that you use `subprocess` instead, and linked you straight to [a section that shows exactly what you're trying to do](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements). I don't know why you expect us to be able to explain it better than the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("ls -l | grep %s | awk '{ print $9 }'" % mask, 
    shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

The `shell=True` is required as the pipeline is run by the shell, otherwise you get a  `No such file or directory`.

In Python 2.7 you can also use

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    "ls -l | grep %s | awk '{ print $9 }'" % mask
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
```

But I find it cumbersome to use as it throws a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` if the pipeline returns exit code other than 0, and to capture both stdout and stderr you need to interleave them both, which makes it unusable for many cases.

Comment: is there any way to get the result as an array or list instead of a string?

Comment: You have a string, isn't it good enough? stdout, stderr is a stream of bytes, not a list. If you need a list use for example stdout.splitlines()

Comment: He only really needs `check_output` here; there's no reason to create a `Popen` and call `communicate` unless you also have input to send it (or need to do other stuff between the creation and communicating, etc.).

Comment: Ah indeed, if he has 2.7. I always forgot that as I find it cumbersome to use, throws exceptions on nonzero exit and so forth.